# Magento - returns blank / empty success page

Tags: magento

I have a problem with the succes page from Magento. Hope somebody can help me with.
What is the problem; The whole site works completely, no errors at all. But when a customer fills in the comple onepage checkout, the customer goes to the payment service provider (PSP) to do their payment. The PSP sends the customer back to {domein}/checkout/onepage/success, which should be right. But... this page is completly empty. I already changed the memory_limit, enabled the developers log, enabled the display_errors in index.php and viewed the log files in Apache. But nothing is shown as error on the page and now errors are shown in the log files.

The orders are processed successfully, so only the displaying is wrong.

Please help with this problem or with a workaround. I need this page to track the affiliates, these need the transactionID and transactionamount.

PS: we use Magento 1.7.0.2, theme ma_housestore and the PSP Buckaroo

Comment: In this case, you should Mage log at the start and every few lines after of `successAction` method, which ensures it's properly called and where it got stuck..

Comment: Hi Kalpesh Mehta, thank you for your answer. In which file do I have to set this up? Because I think that the success.phtml isn't even be called.

Comment: that means your `successAction` is not been properly called. Check in Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php file you will find success action there.

Comment: Kalpesh Mehta, thank you a million times...!!!! We had a wrong template call in app/design/frontend/default/ma_housestore/layout/checkout.xml

Comment: I would, but you placed the solution as a comment, not as an answer. Please place it again as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: my bad.. I have put it in answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should Mage log at the start and every few lines after of successAction method, which ensures it's properly called and where it got stuck.

In your case, `successAction` is not been properly called. Check in `Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php` file you will find success action there.