# Magento onepage checkout blank without errors

Tags: php, magento

We are running magento 1.8.x.x

Upon completing the onepage checkout, the success page is blank.

I have checked the following :

var/log/exception.log
apache error_log
php error.log

And there are no visible errors. Most of the resources online regarding this problem says to check the logs for a clue to this problem, but I don't see any. I can confirm that other exceptions are being logged if I break a piece of code on purpose.

[Magento - returns blank / empty success page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009620/magento-returns-blank-empty-success-page)

This stackoverflow page suggested to mage:log() the successAction method every couple of lines to see where it fails. This is what I did (the numbers next to zzz corresponds to the line in the OnepageController.php file) :

```
 public function successAction()
{
        Mage::log('zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz277');
    $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
    if (!$session->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }
Mage::log('zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz283');
    $lastQuoteId = $session->getLastQuoteId();
    $lastOrderId = $session->getLastOrderId();
    $lastRecurringProfiles = $session->getLastRecurringProfileIds();
    if (!$lastQuoteId || (!$lastOrderId && empty($lastRecurringProfiles))) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }
Mage::log('zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz291');
    $session->clear();
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));
    $this->renderLayout();
Mage::log('zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz297');
}
```

I can confirm that the successAction function appears to complete successfully as per my log files :

```
2014-02-26T17:07:08+00:00 DEBUG (7): zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz277
2014-02-26T17:07:08+00:00 DEBUG (7): zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz283
2014-02-26T17:07:08+00:00 DEBUG (7): zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz291
2014-02-26T17:07:09+00:00 DEBUG (7): zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz297
```

I have checked that the order appears to complete successfully on the back-end.

I have also confirmed that the checkout.xml file is calling the correct file :

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
    <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

I am really at my wits end here. I have absolutely no idea where to go look for the problem without an error message.

I thought I would be able to to a line by line debug on what is exactly failing, but I have absolutely no idea how to do that either.

Any suggestions, resources or gifts from the heavens would be appreciated. I don't know what else to do.

***EDIT***

So i finally figured out the problem. There was an PDF extension plugging into the success page that allows a client to print the order as PDF. This extension was disabled on the back-end, and after enabling it the success page is working again.

I found this by putting an XML dump below the renderLayout(); method in the successAction function with this code :

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
die(Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode()->asXML());
```

I did a search for "success" and found this pdf extension plugging into onepage_success.